# How to add java application to html/php website?

Tags: java, php, html

I never deal with java before. Recently I want to add a game Metal Slug into my website, I got the game source codes from http://www.hackchina.com/en/cont/45242 , but the game is in Java format, is it possible to add the Java game into a html/php website?

Do I need to modify the Java codes? Or I just need to write html to embed the Java game? Mind to show me the example of codes or reference or terms for searching that might help me out?

Is there any place I can download the source codes of Metal Slug game which can embed to website? Haha. I need to modify the game codes because my website allow users to buy the cloth/dress of characters in the game, so I need to change the outfits of the characters in the game...

Comment: Is the game based on Java Applets? I behind a firewall (So I am not able to open the link you provided)

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to add the Java game into a html/php website?

If it is Java based, it can either be embedded in a web page ([applet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info)) or launched from a web page (frame launched with [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)).

Natives (e.g. DLLs) cause a challenge for applets.  Either you can launch them free floating with web start, embedded with web start (requires 'next generation' plug-in2 JRE) or otherwise the user needs to run an installer that puts them somewhere that is on the path for Java related natives.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a game which needs to be installed on the users drive. You can not embed it in an html file.

Comment: Is there any place I can download the source codes of Metal Slug game which can embed to website? Haha. I need to modify the game codes because my website allow users to buy the cloth/dress of characters in the game, so I need to change the outfits of the characters in the game...